# bottom navigation bar not switching tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I want to  use fancy bottom navigation in flutter. When i switch between tabs, it is showing the tab switching only at the navigation bar but, The body is not switching. It is not showing another tabs as i switch.
Here's my code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: _getPage(currentPage),
   bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
          key: bottomNavigationKey,
          tabs: [
            TabData(iconData: Icons.home,title: 'Home'),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.search, title: 'Search'),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.person, title: 'Profile'),
          ],
          onTabChangedListener:   (position){
            setState(() {
              currentPage = position;
              final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                  bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
              fState.setPage(position);
              print('currentPage = $currentPage');
            });
          },
        )
);

_getPage(int page){
  switch(page) {
    case 0:
      return Page1();
    case 1:
      return Search();
    case 2:
      return Profile();
  }
}
```

Comment: When it is not working? 1. While swapping or While clicking on the tab

Comment: @jitsm555 not working any any events(swapping or clicking on tab). Showing same page when i click tabs or swipe tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the GlobalKey here. It is enough to just set the `currentPage` value in the setState.

The Dev Nathan Withers writes [here](https://pub.dev/packages/fancy_bottom_navigation) that the key prop defaults to null and is only used for *Programmatic Selection* of tabs. This special use case is only relevant if you want to change tabs by not clicking on the actual buttons. You don't need this feature. You can check out the [example](https://github.com/tunitowen/fancy_bottom_navigation/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) at line 48 to 50 for an actual use-case for the key prop.

Also examine if an `IndexedStack` suits you. It saves the pages state. You're _getPage() method destroys and builds each page new on each switch.

I put everything together in this example:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _currentPage,
          children: [StartView(), AllServicesView()],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
        tabs: [
          TabData(iconData: Icons.home,title: 'Home'),
          TabData(iconData: Icons.search, title: 'Search'),
        ],
        onTabChangedListener: (position){
          setState(() {
            _currentPage = position;
            print('currentPage = $_currentPage');
          });
        },
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: hey @Nicolas Klein , thanks for your suggestion. But, that is also not working. still the same problem. No movement. It is showing an error

"E/flutter ( 5618): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): FancyBottomNavigationState#b25d9(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
".

How to mount the widget?